# (Android Studio) My Tic-Tac-Toe game is crashing due to (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick) error

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android. I have created a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game in Android Studio. It has a grid and a status bar which tells whose turn it is and also who has won. I have also added a method to reset the game. The game works fine but whenever a player wins the game crashes (TicTacToeme has stopped).
 **I have also tried to initialize some variables but that didn't worked for me.**
Here is my full MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.jashanubhi.tictactoeme;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int activePlayer = 0;
    boolean gameActive = true;
    int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
    int[][] winningPositions = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8},
                                {0,4,8}, {2,4,6},
                                {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}};

    public void playerTap(View view) {
        ImageView img;
        img = (ImageView) view;
        int tappedImage;
        tappedImage = Integer.parseInt(img.getTag().toString());
        TextView status;
        status = findViewById(R.id.status);
        if (gameState[tappedImage] == 2 && gameActive) {
            gameState[tappedImage] = activePlayer;
            img.setTranslationY(-1000f);
            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                activePlayer = 1;
                status.setText("O's Turn - Tap to Play");
            } else {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                activePlayer = 0;
                status.setText("X's Turn - Tap to Play");
            }
            img.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(300);
        }
        for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {
            if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] && gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]]
                    && gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {
                if (winningPosition[0] == 0) {
                    status.setText("X has won");
                }
                if (winningPosition[0] == 1) {
                    status.setText("O has won");
                }
                gameActive = false;
            }
        }
        if(!gameActive){
            gameReset(view);
        }
    }

    public void gameReset(View view){
        activePlayer = 0;
        gameActive = true;
        for(int i = 0; i <= gameState.length; i++){
            gameState[i] = 2;
        }
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView0)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8)).setImageResource(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Here is my Logcat(only error):

```
2020-03-29 15:15:36.635 6517-6517/com.jashanubhi.tictactoeme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jashanubhi.tictactoeme, PID: 6517
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9
        at com.jashanubhi.tictactoeme.MainActivity.gameReset(MainActivity.java:61)
        at com.jashanubhi.tictactoeme.MainActivity.playerTap(MainActivity.java:53)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="38dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="398dp"
        android:layout_height="398dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/grid" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X's Turn - Tap to Play"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="398dp"
        android:layout_height="398dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView0"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="0" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="2" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="4" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="5" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="6" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="7" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playerTap"
                android:padding="23sp"
                android:tag="8" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `gameReset` function you are getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9`
 because of the loop inside there.
 you are doing `for(int i = 0; i <= gameState.length; i++)` but your term for the loop to stop is `i<=gameState.length` instead of `i<gameState.length`
 this cause you to access the array in the array length pos for example if the array length is 5 and you want to get the 5th which is the maximum place you can access in the array you should do `arr[4]` but you are trying to access `arr[5]` which is not in the array therefore you are getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @JashanUbhi please mark my question as the correct one.